# Como criar "options" no Select a partir de uma planilha?

Tags: c#, html5, html-select

Gostaria de saber se é possível gerar options dinamicamente na seleção pelo C#?

Por exemplo, tenho a minha seleção :

```
 <select id="Selecao_itens" multiple="multiple" runat= server  size="3" class="selection">
   <option value="Celula1 da planilha">Desejo criar esses options</option>    
</select>
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida, explique melhor o seu cenário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na view eu utilizo assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_Funcionalidade, controller.ListarFuncionalidade() as SelectList, "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Crio um método no controller para listar os dados quem vem de algum lugar trago para a tela com o tipo `SelectList`.

Exemplo:

```
public SelectList ListarFuncionalidade(object id = null)
{
    var funcionalidade = _IFuncionalidadeApplicationService.GetAllAsNoTracking().ToList();

    IList<FuncionalidadeViewModel> funcionalidadeViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Funcionalidade>, IList<FuncionalidadeViewModel>>(funcionalidade);

    return new SelectList(funcionalidadeViewModel, "ID", "Nome", id);
}
```